# Inflate multiple layouts in listview using json data

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I need a listview like the one below. The data is obtained from json. I know it is regarding inflating layouts within the baseadapter.
But I am not sure on how to use this when it comes to json data.

[image: Image of the listview]

So far my code is :

```
public class CurriculumAdap extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;    

    public CurriculumAdap(Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
    }    

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {            
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 3;
    }
    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {    
        TextView topic;
        TextView subtopic;
        TextView lecture;
        ImageView img;
        TextView title;
        ProgressBar complete;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        View itemView ;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

       //@SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
        //View itemView;
        itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adap, parent, false);
        resultp = data.get(position);

        topic = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.t1);
        subtopic = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.t2);
        lecture = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.t3);

        topic.setText(resultp.get("topic_title"));
        subtopic.setText(resultp.get("sub_topic_title"));
        lecture.setText(resultp.get("lecture_title"));

        return itemView;    
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your json data look like? I would suggest you convert the json data into an object and use that in your adapter.

Comment: topic.setText(resultp.get("topic_title"));
This sets the first textview to the value displayed in "topic_title" which i got from json. so i got the json data in fact.

Comment: Okay so where do you have a problem? So as per your above comment you are getting the data and you are able to set it into the views. So the issue?

Comment: @S.A.NortonStanley Actually i got the output!!! Thanx anyways :)